# Google Data Studio DATE_DIFF and CASE

Tags: looker-studio

I have code:

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), TODATE(Дата регистрации,"%Y%m%d","%Y%m%d")) > 90 THEN 'Менеджер'
    ELSE "Стажер" 
END
```

But it returns

Invalid formula - Invalid input expression. - WHEN conditions must compare a dimension or metric with a literal value.

Every time. How can i fix it?
So the code

```
DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), TODATE(Дата регистрации,"%Y%m%d","%Y%m%d"))
```

returns number of days that i need.

i've tried to do CAST and CEIL but it is not helping...
also tried with between - same story..

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird limitation in DataStudio.  Instead of doing everything in a single field, create a new field with the expression:

```
DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), TODATE(Дата регистрации,"%Y%m%d","%Y%m%d"))
```

and then, another field with your case statement:

```
CASE 
    WHEN new_field > 90 THEN 'Менеджер'
    ELSE "Стажер" 
END
```

This should do the job.

Comment: oh, thank u. But i dont understand. i create new field, but cant refer to it in next field. 
Can u explain me plz?)

Comment: You need to add the new field to your Data Source (under Resources > Manage added data sources) . If you are creating the field when you add a dimension to a chart, it won't work.